# Show and Hide content independently

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a feature to show or hide a content when click upon. The problem is when I click on the button all the content is being shown. I want it to work independently

**HTML**

```
<div class="case_study">
    <button class="open_case" type="Button">Show Case Study</button>

    <div class="case show_case">
    <p>case study here</p>
    <button class="close_study" type="button"> Close Study</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="case_study">
    <button class="open_case" type="Button">Show Case Study</button>

    <div class="case show_case">
        <p>case study here</p>
        <button class="close_study" type="button"> Close Study</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.case_study .open_case').click(function(){
        $('.case').removeClass('show_case')
    })

    $('.case_study .close_study').click(function(){
        $('.case').addClass('show_case')  
    })
})
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
.case{
   margin:20px;
   height:500px;
   width:500px; 
   background-color:teal; 
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
  -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-in; 
  opacity: 1
}

.show_case{
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
   -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    opacity: 0; 
}
```

Comment: It is a bit dsiturbing that the class ´show_case´ actually hide the content...

Comment: sorry about my naming conventions will have to work on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your html, you could do like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.case_study .open_case').click(function(){
        $(this).next().removeClass('show_case');
    });

    $('.case_study .close_study').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('div').addClass('show_case');
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the quick solution. Was about to check the jquery library to find a solution for my problem

Answer (score 0):

you can use show() and hide ()

```
<div class="case_study">
    <button class="open_case" type="Button" onClick="fun1()">Show Case Study</button>

    <div class="case show_case" id="d1">
    <p>case study here</p>
    <button class="close_study" type="button"> Close Study</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="case_study">
    <button class="open_case" type="Button" onClick="fun2()">Show Case Study</button>

    <div class="case show_case" id="d2">
        <p>case study here</p>
        <button class="close_study" type="button"> Close Study</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now in javascript

```
fun1()
{
    if (!$('#d1').is(':visible'))
    {
        $('#d1').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#d1').hide();
    }
}

fun2()
{
    if (!$('#d2').is(':visible'))
    {
        $('#d2').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#d2').hide();
    }
}
```

Also include jquery files.